# Glassfish Logger Settings

Tags: logging, glassfish

Through Glassfish admin page i can define log level to any class/package of my web application (Configurations > server-config > Logger Settings > Log Levels).

But is it possible to define those settings on web application deployment with some properties file?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the logging implementation your application is using. For example, if you are using log4j in your application simply include a log4j.properties or log4j.xml file in the classpath of your application. If you are using *shudder* java.util.logging you can do something similar with a properties file. SLF4J etc can be configured similarly as well.

Comment: Yes, as i know, for `log4j` i can simply use `log4j.properties` in my resource folder without any other configurations. But i'm trying to use `java.util.logging`. Was thinking to place `logging.properties` in resource folder with defined `.level=ALL`, but it not helps. Looks like some additional configurations are needed, but can't find which ones.